# Create Dynamic Json from csv using Groovy in Jmeter

Tags: json, groovy, jmeter

I am trying to create a json using CSV data using Groovy scripting and pass the same in the request body in jmeter but I am not able to create the data:

```
CSV Created:

0.0.0.0,255.255.255.255
10.0.0.1,255.0.0.0
10.0.0.2,255.0.0.1

Request body needed as :

{"Rule":{"__type":"AndroidSamsungDeviceRelocationRule","RuleId":0,"Name":"Test","DeviceFamily":6,"Targets":{"Groups":[{"Id":"0000000007.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000"}],"Devices":[]},"Priority":0,"IsEnabled":true,"StartDate":"/Date(1536856632768)/","EndDate":null,"Mappings":[{"RelocationTarget":{"Id":"0000000007.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000","Name":"100MB","Path":"\\\\100MB\\","PathVisible":"\\\\100MB\\"},"IPRange":[{"From":"0.0.0.0","To":"255.255.255.255"}...]}],"EnrollmentCertificateId":null,"EnrollmentCertificateName":""}}
```

Need the IP address for parameters from and to that are their in the csv in a single request.

code I have tried is :

```
@Grab('com.xlson.groovycsv:groovycsv:1.3')
import static com.xlson.groovycsv.CsvParser.parseCsv

fh = new File('examples/data/process_csv_file.csv')
def csv_content = fh.getText('utf-8')

def data_iterator = parseCsv(csv_content, separator: ';', readFirstLine: true)

for (line in data_iterator) {
    sum = line[0] as String
    destination = line[1] as String
}

def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()

builder({
   Rule:{
      __type:"AndroidSamsungDeviceRelocationRule",
      RuleId:0,
      Name:"Test",
      DeviceFamily:6,
      Targets:{
         Groups:[
            {
               Id:"0000000007.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000"
            }
         ],
         Devices:[

         ]
      },
      Priority:0,
      IsEnabled:true,
      StartDate:"/Date(1536856632768)/",
      EndDate:null,
      Mappings:[
         {
            RelocationTarget:{
               Id:"0000000007.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000",
               Name:"100MB",
               Path:"\\\\100MB\\",
               PathVisible:"\\\\100MB\\"
            },
            IPRange:[
               {
                  "From":"sum",
                  "To":"destination"
               }
            ]
         }
      ],
      EnrollmentCertificateId:null,
      EnrollmentCertificateName:""
   }
})

sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('',builder.toPrettyString(),'')
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true);
```

When I am running this through JSR223 Preprocessor I am getting blank request with error HTTP 400.

I need to create a dynamic IPRange loop for number of IPs available in CSV

Answer (score 0):

just check how you are using `JsonBuilder`

the following two variants produce the same result:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def builder = new JsonBuilder()

builder({
    Rule{
        RuleId(0)
        Devices([1,2,3])
    }
})
println builder.toPrettyString()
```

another way is to define maps/arrays sequence and then convert to json

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def data = [
    Rule: [
        RuleId:0,
        Devices:[1,2,3]
    ]
]
println new JsonBuilder(data).toPrettyString()
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use [@Grab](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/lang/Grab.html) annotation in [JSR223 Test Elements](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) therefore your test fails at the early beginning.

You can try using below code which should generate the JSON you're looking for without any external dependencies:

```
def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()

@groovy.transform.Immutable
class IPRange {
    String From
    String To
}

def ipRanges = new File("examples/data/process_csv_file.csv").readLines().collect { line -> new IPRange(line.split(",")[0], line.split(",")[1]) }
builder.Rule(

        __type: "AndroidSamsungDeviceRelocationRule",
        RuleId: 0,
        Name: "Test",
        DeviceFamily: 6,
        Targets:
                [
                        Groups :
                                [
                                        [
                                                Id: "0000000007.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000",
                                        ]
                                ],
                        Devices:
                                [

                                ]
                ],
        Priority: 0,
        IsEnabled: true,
        StartDate: "/Date(1536856632768)/",
        EndDate: null,
        Mappings:
                [
                        [
                                RelocationTarget:
                                        [
                                                Id         : "0000000007.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000.0000000000",
                                                Name       : "100MB",
                                                Path       : "\\\\100MB\\",
                                                PathVisible: "\\\\100MB\\"
                                        ],
                                IPRange         : ipRanges.collect() {
                                    [
                                            From: it.From,
                                            To  : it.To
                                    ]
                                }

                        ]
                ],
        EnrollmentCertificateId: null,
        EnrollmentCertificateName: ""

)

sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('', builder.toPrettyString(), '')
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true);
```

More information:

- [Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)