# Groovy No such property error while creating dynamic json

Tags: groovy, jmeter, jsr223, jsonbuilder

I am trying to create a dynamic json using csv data in jmeter with JSR223 PreProcessor

Below is the code for the same I am using CSV for data for Id and Name:

```
def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()

@groovy.transform.Immutable
class Items {
    String Id
    String Name
}

def items = new File("Item.txt").readLines().collect { line -> new Items(line.split(",")[0], line.split(",")[1]) }
builder.Rule(

        __type: "DataCollectionRule",
        DeviceFamily: '${__P(DeviceFamily)}',
        RuleId: 0,
        Name: 'test-${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss)}-${__counter(TRUE,)}',
        Targets:
                [
                        Groups :
                                [
                                        [
                                                Id: '${logicalid1_1}',
                                        ]
                                ],
                        Devices:
                                [

                                ]
                ],
        StartDate: '/Date(${__time(,)})/',        
        IsEnabled: true,
        Priority: 0,
        AlertType: 0,
        DeliverySchedule:
                [
                                                Id         :   1,
                                                Name       :  "Every 30 Minutes",
                                                Period     :  "30M"

                ],
        CollectionSchedule:                      
               [
                                              Id         :   1,
                                                Name       :  "Every 30 Minutes",
                                                Period     :  "30M"
              ],                    
        Items  : items.collect() [
        [

                                                Id         : it.Id,
                                                Name       : it.Name                                                

        ]
                ],
        LocationAccuracy:
                [
                                                UseGPS     :  false,
                                       DistanceInMeters : 100,
                                       ReportToServer  : true,
                                       AccuracyInMeters : 10
             ],
          HasDolphinCounters: false,
          EnrollmentCertificateId: null,
          EnrollmentCertificateName: "",
        DatabaseHighWatermark: 28,
        DatabaseLowWatermark: 14,
        DeviceHighWatermark: 400,
        DeviceLowWatermark:  200

)

sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('', builder.toPrettyString(), '')
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true);
```

While running the test I am getting HTTP 400 with Bad Request

Log message is as shown below:

2018-09-24 13:49:23,669 ERROR o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PreProcessor
javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: it for class: Script32
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:320) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyCompiledScript.eval(GroovyCompiledScript.java:72) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_151]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:221) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.modifiers.JSR223PreProcessor.process(JSR223PreProcessor.java:44) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPreProcessors(JMeterThread.java:849) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:467) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:416) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:250) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:4.0 r1823414]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_151]
Caused by: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: it for class: Script32
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:53) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:52) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:307) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    at Script32.run(Script32.groovy:46) ~[?:?]
    at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223.GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:317) ~[groovy-all-2.4.13.jar:2.4.13]
    ... 9 more

CSV is as follows :

```
   -1,BatteryStatus
    -3,AvailableMemory
    -5,AvailableStorage
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `{}` for a closure here:

```
items.collect() { // wrong: [
    // ...
} // wrong: ]
```

Or just `items.collect { ... }`

With the `[]` the compiler will see that as a map literal and you get above errors (`it` is undefined)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be copying and pasting the [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52399427/2897748) more accurately, to wit your "Items" section should look like:

```
Items: items.collect() {
    [
            Id  : it.Id,
            Name: it.Name
    ]
}
```

---

Also be aware that you should not be using [JMeter Functions and or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in Groovy scripts directly as it conflicts with [GString Template](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/text/GStringTemplateEngine.html) feature and makes [caching of compiled scripts](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) impossible negatively impacting performance.

So I would also recommend changing:

- `${__P(DeviceFamily)` to `props.get('DeviceFamily`)`
- `${__time(yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss)}` to `new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd'T'hh:mm:ss")`
- etc.

See [The Groovy Templates Cheat Sheet for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-groovy-templates-cheat-sheet-for-jmeter) article for more information on Groovy scripting in JMeter if needed